# Git - push code to existing repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

My friend has created a project on BitBucket. I downloaded it as ZIP file, working on that and deployed the code to Heroku. Now I would need to push this code, which I currently have on my machine, to the original repository on BitBucket.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create own fork and create pull request.